# CSS selector for sentences after first sentence

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have question about css selector. I want to select all sentences after first sentence 
in container. For first sentence there is no problem:

```
 :first-line
```

But I can't find way to select sentences "after first line". I tried something like this but
it don't working.

```
:not(:first-line)
```

Here is fiddle with selected first sentence but this don't solve my problem. 
http://jsfiddle.net/zono/2bDx8/
Best regards.

Comment: Do you mean "after first *line*"? `:first-line` does not select sentences.

Comment: `:first-line` selects the first line, as it says, not the first sentence. It ends after the first line break. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-line/

Comment: A sentence can span multiple lines. Better say line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that the height of each line defaults to 1em. Setting the max height and overflow hidden will only show the first **line** of the sentence.

http://jsfiddle.net/AqaLJ/2/

```
p  {
 max-height: 1em;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Another approach could be to use text-overflow: ellipsis. This is much more user-friendly as it indicates that the sentence has more text and is trimmed.
http://jsfiddle.net/Wws6L/11/

```
p {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This does not select sentences (which is what the question title says) or lines after the first line (which might be what the question was meant to ask).

Comment: Again a sentence is not a line of text. I now figured out what is wanted. In the comments is stated he wants to show only the first line of the **sentence**. I will update the answer. This cannot be done with :first-line but needs another approach.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [`::first-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-line) doesn't select the first `sentence`, it selects the first `line`, whose end is marked by a line break. That said, I don't think there is one selector for what you demand, but here's a neat trick:

```
.linesOfText {       /* :not(:first-line)) */
   background-color: blue;
}

.linesOfText::first-line{
    background:white;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/2bDx8/1/)**

Comment: Тhe problem is that I want to hide all the sentences after the first. I used colorс just for example. If I tried display: none and display: inline in this case it don't work. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zono/2bDx8/3/

Comment: @GeorgiNaumov You should ask about your actual need, not an irrelevant example. The solution to your actual problem is not to use `:first-line` at all: http://jsfiddle.net/2bDx8/4/ (And "sentence" still doesn't mean what you think it means.)

Comment: Thank you. Please post answer because I must accept it.

Comment: You should have mentioned this in your question: 'Тhe problem is that I want to hide all the sentences after the first.'